How to validate date in laravel/formrequest
I have this type of date:
"Date": "2024-09-06T06:58:19.326Z",

How should I validate it in my FormRequest in Laravel?
I've tried this:
'required|date_format:Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z'

and this:
date_format:Y-m-d

but I get 422 every time.

u from the date format represents microseconds (6 digits). To match your datetime format you need to use v which represents only milliseconds (3 digits).
Therfor the solution would be:
'required|date_format:Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v\Z'

See: https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.format.php

Simply adding this will resolve your issue,
Solution 1:
'required|date',

But if you need some exact solution you can do something like this,
Solution 2:
'required|date_format:Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v\Z',

But the recommended solution is the first one, since it handles most of the date formats. Hope this resolves your issue.

'date' => [
    'required',
    'regex:/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}Z$/'
]


That's a good answer, but i prefer not to use regex in my requests :)

Try This to valiadte your this date "2024-09-06T06:58:19.326Z" format
'date_field' => [
        'required',
        'date_format:Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z' // Custom format for ISO 8601 with milliseconds and timezone designator
    ],


what is the difference between your solution and what OP posting in his question ? also this question already have a definitive answer

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
